# How to sort twodimensional array by how closely it matches a word?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/t226j4ox/6/

I have a 2D array which contains an unsorted list of names.

I'm trying to figure out how to sort the names in the array by how closely they match the user's keyword. In the jsfiddle, I set to user's keyword to "Be" for testing purposes. Ideally, when you hit the "Sort Names" button, the array would be sorted so that names starting with 'Be' appear first.

How should this be achieved?

HTML

```
<div id="button1">
Display All Names
</div>

<br>

<div id="button2">
Sort Names
</div>
```

CSS

```
#button1{
  background:cornflowerblue;
  height:20px;
  width:200px;
  cursor:pointer;
  text-align:center;
}

#button2{
  background:mediumpurple;
  height:20px;
  width:200px;
  cursor:pointer;
  text-align:center;
}
```

JS

```
var nameList = "";

var names = [["name","Bradley"],["id","Brooke"],["name","Bobby"],
             ["name","Bethany"],["id","Benjamin"],["name","Bella"],
             ["name","Blake"],["id","Beatrice"],["name","Baby"],
             ["name","Byron"],["id","Buster"],["name","Bailey"],
             ["name","Betty"],["id","Billy"],["name","Brady"]];



var userKeyword = "Be";


$(document).on('click', '#button1', function(event) { 
        for (i=0; i<5; i++){
            nameList += names[i][1] + " ";        
        }

        alert(nameList);

}); 

$(document).on('click', '#button2', function(event) { 

});
```

Comment: Before I tell you an answer, what do you think you will need to solve the problem?

Comment: Check if array item's first letter matches the term's first letter, and so on and so on. But I figure there has to be a formal way to do this rather than manually creating your own code for it.

Comment: what is with the id/name... also seems weird you are not using Objects.

Comment: Do you have an algorithm that determines the match score?

Comment: No, not yet. I just didn't want to start coding something that may already have a premade function (I saw that they have premade functions for sorting alphabetically and numerically), but I guess this must be done manually. So, to be clear, you recommend comparing the first letters, the second letters, etc of the array VS the user's term, and then scoring each array member by how many letters matched, and then rearranging the array based on each's score? Thank you. oh, and the id/name thing is weird but needed. As for objects, I don't have much experience with them. Would that make it easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sort` function

```js
var nameList = '';

var names = [
 ['name','Bradley'],
 ['id','Brooke'],
 ['name','Bobby'],
 ['name','Bethany'],
 ['id','Benjamin'],
 ['name','Bella'],
 ['name','Blake'],
 ['id','Beatrice'],
 ['name','Baby'],
 ['name','Byron'],
 ['id','Buster'],
 ['name','Bailey'],
 ['name','Betty'],
 ['id','Billy'],
 ['name','Brady']
];

var userKeyword = 'Be';

names.sort(function(a, b){
 return b[1].indexOf(userKeyword) - a[1].indexOf(userKeyword);
});


document.write(JSON.stringify(names));
```